# Reposync - is it safe to abort?

Tags: yum

I accidentally executed reposync on our Linux machine and it started performing hundreds of .rpm file downloads...

Being a Windows guy with limited Linux knowledge, I found this: `synchronize yum repositories to a local directory` in the docs, but I don't understand exactly what that means (which yum repositories?) and what's the impact (I know what yum is though).

Can anyone give me a short explanation?

Also, is it safe to abort it? Should I reverse it somehow?

This Linux machine has a small HD (100MB only I think) and I'm worried I'm gonna clog the HD with junk I don't need...

Just in case, here's uname -a output:

`Linux testmds 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally typed `reposync` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>?  Look before you leap...

> I don't understand exactly what that means (which yum repositories?)

The software you install via `yum` etc. comes from online *repositories*.  You can find some information about them (such as the URLs) in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, although it is not very interesting.  You should not need to change that stuff manually either.

You can peruse the repositories from a browser, e.g., here's [the "updates" repo for x86_64 Fedora 21](http://fedora.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/linux/updates/21/x86_64/).  But you don't need to do this and there's no information, just access to the packages.  Normally you should use the package manager to install things -- I am not recommending you download `.rpm`s this way, just pointing out what the repositories are.

`Repoquery` presumably mirrors one or more of these, initiating the downloading of a tishload of `.rpm` packages in an alphabetized hierarchy.  According to the man page, these will go into "the current directory" unless you specify otherwise, so they should not be hard find.

> is it safe to abort it? Should I reverse it somehow?

I'm sure it is safe to just stop it, and I doubt very much it has done anything other than download stuff, so there's nothing to reverse -- just a lot of files to delete.

Comment: I typed "repos", hit tab assuming I'll get "reposurgeon" which I was trying to run and hit enter...

Thanks, I just `rm -rf base` and everything seems fine :)